# A problem in my awk script. -condition : using variable in awk. - aim : print specific column started count variable in text

Tags: awk

I want to print the whole line with specific column started count variable in text.

- file.log format

```
1 101010 101010 4.0001 my home
2 101010 101010 5.0001 my home
3 101010 101010 6.0001 my home
4 101010 101010 7.0001 my home
```

- my script

```
count=4
awk -v cnt="$count" '$4 ~ /^[cnt]\./' file.log
```

- I want this result.

```
1 101010 101010 4.0001 my home
```

- But my result is nothing....

Please tell me the wrong point of my script.

Comment: FYI `[cnt]` is a bracket expression which means "a single character which is either of the letters c, n, or t". See https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03_05.

Answer (score 3):

You need NOT to use `awk` variable in a literal regexp, use `int` function here to convert 4th field as interger and then compare it directly with variable like:

```
count="4"
awk -v cnt="$count" 'int($4)==cnt' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** First passing shell variable `count` to `cnt` as an `awk` variable. Then using `int` function on 4th field to get only integer part eg--> from `4.0001` to `4` to make an exact comparison with `cnt` and once its equal it will print that line.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a dynamic (aka computed) instead of literal regexp:

```
awk -v cnt="$count" '$4 ~ ("^" cnt "[.]")' file.log
```

See [How do I use shell variables in an awk script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075671/how-do-i-use-shell-variables-in-an-awk-script) and https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Computed-Regexps.